# How to perform git diff on one folder in master branch

Tags: git, github

is there a git command to get the GIT diff of a particular folder in repository.

I did check git diff myfolder -> Not works as expected

Comment: "Not works as expected". Because diffs work against _something_... Your `git diff <DIR>` shows the diff against _the working copy_ implicitly, but your question title says "in master branch". How is that reflected in your command? Is your working copy in dirty state? What branch are you at? Try using `git diff <COMMIT>~1..<COMMIT> -- <DIR>` where `<COMMIT>` may be `master` (at least this is how I understood what you're asking).

Comment: I meant GIT DIFF <Directory> not providing results to me when I ran on my branch. I want to run GIT diff on folder so I am trying locally with my feature branch to get the results but I am not getting.

Comment: It sounds like you want `git diff <LEFT_BRANCH>..<RIGHT_BRANCH> -- <DIR>` where all of the parameters are your `master`, `feature`, and `myfolder` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

As [the `git diff` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) says right at the beginning:

> `git diff [options] [--] [path...]`
>       This form is to view the changes you made relative to the index (staging area for the next commit). In other words, the differences are what you *could* tell Git to further add to the index but you still haven’t.

So:

```
git diff myfolder
```

does not compare *any* **committed** files to the current working tree copy of files within `myfolder/`.  Instead, it compares the copies of those files that are in Git's *index* (aka *staging area*) to the copies in your working tree.

You state that you wish to compare the *committed* copies of some files to the copies in your working tree.  Read the rest of the introduction to `git diff` to find out how to do that:

> `git diff [options] commit [--] [path...]`

Note that this form *requires* a commit specifier before the *`path`* part.  Commit specifiers can take many forms, as listed in [the gitrevisions documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions).  One of these is to use a branch name.  Using the name of a branch generally<sup>1</sup> results in the commit hash ID that corresponds to the latest commit *on* that branch.  So to compare the latest `master` commit's copies of those files to the working tree's copies, you would need:

```
git diff master myfolder
```

The Git documentation is rather dense reading (and loaded with jargon), but it is often pretty accurate, and you should check it carefully.  In this case, studying the first page or so of `git help diff` would have gotten you this answer on your own, plus quite a bit more information.